# Comparison of logstash and xpolog

Tags: logging, logstash, xpolog

can anyone share experience with Logstash or Xpolog. I need to evaluate both and make a recommendation for a global log management system in our enterprise and I'm curious if someone used both or at least one of these and can give some feedback, please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I work for a very large insurance company, we evaluated both solutions, Logstash work well and is open source so the license is free, but requires high technical expertise to deploy and manage, in order to monitor Logstash deployment or have security you need to purchase licenses as well. The collection is working well, though there are no user interfaces and less management flexibility. So if you plan to automate with load of scripts you can overcome this but still going to invest a lot to maintain and develop for long term.

I think that XpoLog is cost effective, even comparing with opensource related cost, we felt its like Atlassian model, great value proposition, easier to deploy and manage, available support and very good analytic engine (this was a sweet spot for us) for our logs. The deployment contains self monitoring and security with no additional charges, and documentation are available online. So after evaluating both solutions and road map we figured XpoLog will be better fit for us. Hope that was helpful.